# Synthetic Division on Polynomials

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, polynomial-math, polynomials

I need to let the user input the coefficients and the divisor, and the degree needs to be 4.

```
def extended_synthetic_division(dividend, divisor):
    '''Fast polynomial division by using Extended Synthetic Division. Also works with non-monic polynomials.'''
    # dividend and divisor are both polynomials, which are here simply lists of coefficients. Eg: x^2 + 3x + 5 will be represented as [1, 3, 5]


    out = list(dividend) # Copy the dividend
    normalizer = divisor[0]
    for i in xrange(len(dividend)-(len(divisor)-1)):
        out[i] /= normalizer # for general polynomial division (when polynomials are non-monic),
                             # we need to normalize by dividing the coefficient with the divisor's first coefficient
        coef = out[i]
        if coef != 0: # useless to multiply if coef is 0
            for j in xrange(1, len(divisor)): # in synthetic division, we always skip the first coefficient of the divisor,
                                          # because it's only used to normalize the dividend coefficients
                out[i + j] += -divisor[j] * coef

    # The resulting out contains both the quotient and the remainder, the remainder being the size of the divisor (the remainder
    # has necessarily the same degree as the divisor since it's what we couldn't divide from the dividend), so we compute the index
    # where this separation is, and return the quotient and remainder.
    separator = -(len(divisor)-1)
    return out[:separator], out[separator:] # return quotient, remainder.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("POLYNOMIAL SYNTHETIC DIVISION")
    N = [-2, -3, 4, 5]
    D = [1, 2]
    print ("  %s / %s =") % (N,D),
    print (" %s remainder %s") % extended_synthetic_division(N, D)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the function `input()`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I am, the thing is the divident requires 4 coefficients, meaning 4 different inputs. On the other hand, the divisor only requires 2 inputs. This is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Ok, let me get this clear: you want something like "Please enter the four divident values, separated by comma >>> -2, -3, 4, 5; "Now please enter the two divisor values, separated by comma >>> 1, 2" -> "Your results are: " ...

Comment: Yeah exactly! Well it can be any number, not necessarily the “-2,-3,4...”

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension and the input method if I understood you correctly:

```py
dividends = [int(dividend) for dividend in input('Enter the dividend values separated by comma').split(',')]
divisors = [ int(divisor) for divisor in input("Enter the divisor 
values seperated by comma').split(',')]
```

If you don't feel comfortable with it, you could also do it in several steps:

```py
    # get the dividends from the user as a string
    user_input = input('Enter the dividends values separated by commas')
     
    # generate a list of ints from the input string
    dividends = [int(dividend) for dividend in user_input.split(',')]  

    # get the divisors from the users as a string
    user_input = input('Enter the divisors values separated by commas')
 
    # generate a list of ints from the input string
    divisors = [int(divisor) for divisor in user_input.split(',')]
```

Comment: You could be more specific in your answer